# Sensor discovery on runtime with ROS?

Tags: ros, messages, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I discovered the ROS project last week and was fascinated about large hardware support and the nice tools for development. Now I try to understand its relevance to my work.

I am interested in scenarios where mobile robots explore their intelligent environment by various external sensors (static sensor nodes and other robots). Each of them provides an electronic data sheet containing all necessary information about range, data format, uncertainty, etc. If a new sensor comes close to the robot for wireless communication it transfers its data sheet via a special pub/sub channel to the robot. It examines the available information and discard them or subscribes to the channel mentioned in the data sheet.

According to the concepts of ROS, are such scenarios implementable in your system, or do I need a predefined msg format in each case, for instance?

Looking forward to your remarks

Best wishes from Germany

Poseidonius

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9355/sensor-discovery-on-runtime-with-ros?/) by [Poseidonius](https://answers.ros.org/users/248/poseidonius/) on ROS Answers with karma: 427 on 2011-03-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wow, sounds like an interesting project!

Because you don't have constant communication between all the elements in your system, you'll want to be running one roscore per device, where each device is a mobile or stationary unit guaranteed to have communication with itself. Then it can communicate with other cores as they come in and out of range.

Some preliminary work on this using OLSR as the network mesh protocol has been done here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/wifi_comm

---

Originally posted by [mikepurvis](https://answers.ros.org/users/270/mikepurvis/) with karma: 1153 on 2011-03-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0